# FFMPEG DASH - Live Streaming a Sequence of MP3 Clips

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am attempting to create a online radio application using FFMPEG - an audio only DASH stream.

I have a directory of mp3 clips (all of the same bitrate and sample size) which I am encoding to the AAC format and outputting to a mpd.

This is the current command I am working with to stream a single mp3 file:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <input>.mp3 -c:a aac -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 -f dash <out>.mpd
```

(Input and output paths have been substituted for < input >.mp3 and < output >.mpd in this snippet)

I am running a web server and have made the mpd accessible on it. I am testing the stream using VLC player at the moment.

**The problem**:
Well, the command works, but it will only work for one clip at a time. Once the next command is run immediately proceeding the completion of the first, VLC player will halt and I need to refresh the player to continue.

I'm aiming for an uninterrupted stream wherein the clips play in sequence.
I imagine the problem is that a new mpd is being created with no reference to the previous one, and what I ought to be doing is appending segments to the existing mpd - but I don't know how to do that using FFMPEG.

**The question**: Is there such a command to append segments to a previously existing mpd file in FFMPEG? or am I coming at this problem all wrong? Perhaps I should be using FFMPEG to format the clips into these segments, but then adjusting the mpd file manually.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Feed the files to ffmpeg using the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer).

Comment: @Gyan, Thanks so much! I've now got a working prototype and I'm on the right track to implement my program. Thanks again :)